# Sort on JSON line chart produces line connecting points in original sort

Tags: json, sorting, charts, line, vega-lite

I'm trying to sort my y-axis of a line chart based on a value, the items on the y-axis does indeed sort, but the lines become unusable because the connecting points are still connecting based on the initial sort (alphabetical), so it creates a jumble of line. Trying to figure out how can I get the sort, to properly connect my points and not jump around using the alphabetical sort?
The first picture the sort is count, so effectively no sort, but the second picture, where the lines no longer connect in order, is using average. Thanks in advance.

[No Sort (using count)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MalXH.png)

[Sort using Average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg4dQ.png)

Chart example
[Link to the sorted chart editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVICTJLrgBPKTPkBfJcm0BrNKEzmccfcNmelmNmyCmDQ4aJjaDHBKOGw0sphhEVEgcZhw2jGCap7o3nCmIHYgcLJQbMpxZC4gAB7VSGRk2nxp+hAMCIogAGY0cILK+uZ9A4VK5tW9-YPoxKZ9bl1uHvqybAhxSHpKMtoJmiBsoehIpNoNvj0jMyDD011s2srp+s-QJRWyVTZFZYKPk2ubREhR+QA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sorting is correct according to your spec. The reason it is muddled is because you have a sum on one axis and average on the other. If you make both the same, the dots can connect properly. e.g.

Both average.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the chart when I have a different aggregation for the sort. The line that I highlighted, it the path the dots connect is still looking at sort based on how they originally were. So the variety axis is now sorted based on the proper aggregation, but the dots connect on the old way. I highlighted the path one of the dots take. For Waseca (yellow line), the Wisconsin No. 38 connects to a No. 475 it would seem, not the category next to it.
[Highlighted Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir1IU.png)